# Use When Case in SQL server to Ruby On Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby, activerecord

I have this query in SQL

```sql
select @cd_x=
Case 
    when tp_x2='ZZZ' then  tp_x3
    when tp_x2='XXX' then  tp_x3
    else
    tp_x2
end 
from table
where id=@id
```

How can I translate this query to a sentence in Ruby on Rails?

Comment: I have assumed that you're using ActiveRecord with Rails, and not a different ORM, such as [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org).

Comment: Yes I'm using activeRecord I'm trying to make conditions at the statements but it doesn't work

Comment: what does "to a sentence" mean?

Comment: Sorry for that... I want to make a query inside a model that I've made previously.. Model.query (:conditions...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you would be looking at something like:

```
@cd_x = table.select("CASE WHEN tp_x2='ZZZ' THEN tp_x3 WHEN tp_x2='XXX' then tp_x3 ELSE tp_x2 END").where(:id => id)
```

I am using this as a model though they created a whole module out of it rather than one line: [Case Statement in ActiveRecord](https://gist.github.com/664645)

Comment: Thanks very much I gonna try this kind of approach

Answer (score 3):

I had a kind a similar problem. I wanted to update more records with one query. Basically an order sorting update, using CASE sql.

```
#List of product ids in sorted order. Get from jqueryui sortable plugin.
#product_ids = [3,1,2,4,7,6,5]

#product_ids.each_with_index do |id, index|
#  Product.where(id: id).update_all(sort_order: index+1)
#end

##CASE syntax example:
##Product.where(id: product_ids).update_all("sort_order = CASE id WHEN 539 THEN 1 WHEN 540 THEN 2 WHEN 542 THEN 3 END")

case_string = "sort_order = CASE id "      

product_ids.each_with_index do |id, index|
  case_string += "WHEN #{id} THEN #{index+1} "
end

case_string += "END"

Product.where(id: product_ids).update_all(case_string)
```